# Can I call a overloaded constructor of the same class in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor, this, multiple-constructors

I know that I can do that with ': this()' but if I do that the overloaded constructor will be excecuted first and I need it to be executed after the the constructor that will call it . . . .  Is complicated to explain let me put some code:

```
Class foo{
    public foo(){
       Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
    public foo(string x) : this(){
       Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

///....

```
Class main{
    public static void main( string [] args ){
       foo f = new foo("the letter is: ");
    }
}
```

In this example the program will show

```
A 
the letter is:
```

but what I want is

```
the letter is: 
A
```

There is a 'elegant way' to do this? I would prefer to avoid extracting the constructor actions to separated method and call them from there.

Comment: This question makes me wonder if you're doing too much in your constructors. IMO a constructor should just capture and store state initialization. Much more than that should be put into methods that the consumer of your object calls.

Comment: acctually what the constructors do it is really simply but some of them initialize more attributes than others. so The ones that initialize 4 attributes needs to initialize the same attributes of the constructor that initialize 3, but the constructor that initialize 3 must see if the constructor with 4 just initialize some value

Comment: Then it sounds like you should just have the constructor(s) that take more parameters call the constructor(s) that take fewer parameters (i.e. : this( value1, value2, value3 ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this pretty easily (unfortunately):

```
class foo {
    public foo( ) {
        Console.WriteLine( "A" );
    }
    public foo( string x ) {
        Console.WriteLine( x );

        var c = this.GetType( ).GetConstructor( new Type[ ] { } );
        c.Invoke( new object[ ] { } );
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
        new foo( "the letter is: " );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you that works!
Now what if I need to call another constructor that receives a parameter?

example:

public foo(){
 }

public foo(string a){
//needs to call foo()
}

public foo(string a, string b){
   //needs to call foo(string)
}

Comment: First, you have to edit the array given to GetConstructor and fill it in with the types your specific constructor accepts, then put the actual parameters into the array passed to Invoke. In your example it becomes new Type[]{typeof(string)} and new object[]{a}

Comment: Thank you vary much works flawlessly, it is just what I need it :)

Comment: You are welcome :) By the way, do you know that accepting answers here on stackoverflow greatly helps the community? See here for details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: At the end it did work as I expected :( when I do that it creates a new instance of the object instead that the same object calls the constructor, so if a initialize a global variable on Foo() when I back to Foo(string) that variable is null becase my object never go thought that code.

You answered my question, but I ask the wrong question for my problem :/ hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Extract the constructor actions to virtual methods and call them from there.

This gives you complete control over the order in which the derived class's functionality runs relative to the base class.

Comment: The only possible drawback of this method (no pun intended) is that you cannot set `readonly` fields in the virtual method.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Of course, because the derived class could be relying on functionality of the base class that uses those read only fields.  It would be *wrong* for them to be mutated after such code is executed.  That you are prevented from falling into this undesirable situation is *good*.

Comment: In a constructor, those fields can be set. In another method, they cannot be set. As such, it is a restriction, a drawback in the range of possible actions. I did not claim that restriction serves no purpose, or that there is no valid reason for it, just that it means you cannot do something in the method that you can do in the constructor.